# Entering a folder with whitespaces and escape characters using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, whitespace

I have access to a list of folders that have a format like
 `lastname, firstname(id)`
When I try to enter the folder from the terminal, it looks like 
`cd test/lastname,\ firstname\(id\)`
I am not sure why there are backslashes where there aren't any spaces. My script has access to the credentials and I generated the exact format with the backslashes, but I still cannot enter the folder from the bash script. The variable I use is like this:
`folder="lastname,\ firstname\(id\)"`

When I do `cd $HOME/test/$folder/`
it says there is not such folder. I tried a couple of solutions suggested on different questions, but haven't worked. Putting it within double quotes on the folder variable, and also on the entire expression also didn't work. I guess I don't know what is going wrong and hence cannot get it to work. It'd be awesome if someone could help me out here!

Comment: can you try `folder='lastname, firstname(id)'` ?

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> The variable I use is like this: `folder="lastname,\ firstname\(id\)"`

Will **not** work. Because the variable then **keeps** the backslash:

```
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux ~]$ folder="lastname,\ firstname\(id\)"
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux ~]$ echo "$folder"
lastname,\ firstname\(id\)
```

Hence, you get this message:

```
cd "slask/$folder" 
bash: cd: slask/lastname,\ firstname\(id\): No such file or directory
```

The easiest way to solve this is to put your variable inside `""`. Like this:

```
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux slask]$ mkdir lastname,\ firstname\(id\)
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux slask]$ folder="lastname, firstname(id)"
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux slask]$ cd "$folder"
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux lastname, firstname(id)]$
```

This way, the shell will not split on the whitespace in the variable. Read more about variables and quoting **[here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)**.

Comment: dang dude! Thanks for educating me on these intricacies. I removed the extra backslashes that I was inserting manually and followed the method you suggested. Works!

Comment: @rookie No problem. Believe me, we have all been there! You posted a really good question.

Answer (score 0):

Quote your expansions (`$folder` is an expansion, a "Parameter expansion"):

```
$ cd "$HOME/test/$folder/"
```

If you assign the value in single quotes:

```
$ folder='lastname, firstname(id)'
```

There is no need for back quotes, and the above `cd` will work correctly.

Comment: I had actually tried the approach with single quotes manually and it worked. But then the problem was that the credentials(firstname/lastname/id) were pulled from different sources and the eventual folder name I created was stored in a variable. Now if I used single quotes, it didnt substitute the variable but used it as is and that's where I got stuck.

Comment: @rookie The take away should be "quote your expansions". That is the real key.